# Bind to current binding context?

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have an item template which is to display a `List<IGrouping<string, string>>`. In order to do this I need to bind an `ItemsSource` to the current binding context, in WPF I would do it something like `{Binding DataContext}` how would I do this in MvvmCross?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Text Key"/> !**IGrouping.Key**!
  <Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/items"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource DataContext" !**This doesn't work, should bind IGrouping as IEnumerable<string>**!
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_myitem"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to the current source by providing an empty path.

To do this, I find the best syntax is just to use "."

```
<Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/items"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ."
   local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_myitem"/>
```

However, some people prefer using an empty string - although I find this a bit less readable

```
<Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/items"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   local:MvxBind="ItemsSource"
   local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_myitem"/>
```

This option - and lots more besides - is discussed in the data-binding article -

**https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding**

(Note: empty string binding was broken in nuget v3.0.9 but should be fixed in v3.0.10 - see [Error when making bind ObservableCollection<string> for a MvxListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729282/error-when-making-bind-observablecollectionstring-for-a-mvxlistview/17729996#17729996))