# How to add bindings to MvxSpinner inside MvxDropdownItemTemplate and MvxItemTemplate

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I pulled this section of code from: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/MoreControls/MoreControls.Droid/Resources/Layout/FirstView.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Mvx.MvxSpinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Shapes; SelectedItem Current" />

    <!--
        could be customised using
        local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/spinner_dropdownitem_shape"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/spinner_item_shape"
    -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        local:MvxBind="Text Current" />
    <MC.ShapeView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        local:MvxBind="Shape Current" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The comment mentions it is possible to customize the look by passing MvxDropDownItemTemplate and MvxItemTemplate a layout.  Let's assume we are going to use this simple layout for both templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Project.Ui.Droid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="Text ???????" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The MvxSpinner displays the enumerated name (`Circle`, `Square`, `Triangle`) as the text for each item.  Without changing the view model, is it possible to create a binding, in the template, that displays the same thing the MvxSpinner displays by default when no template is used?  If so, what would that binding look like?  If that's not possible, what is the best way to accomplish this outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in the template, that displays the same thing the MvxSpinner displays by default when no template is used? If so, what would that binding look like? If that's not possible, what is the best way to accomplish this outcome?

The default template uses `ToString()` on the object.

To achieve the same thing, you can use the `Whole Object` binding. From [the wiki](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding), you should be able to specify using an empty Path or a single Period for the Path. Since we've seen [some issues reported recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205096/default-binding-using-rio-in-mvvmcross/18213781#18213781) with empty Path binding, I recommend using a Period:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Project.Ui.Droid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="Text ." />
</FrameLayout>
```